# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named [keller_protocol]

Tags: python

I have got the error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keller_protocol'" even though this module is already in the library:
/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keller_protocol/

in /keller_protocol folder there are
keller_protocol.py  **ini**.py **pycache** test_keller_protocol

in the test.py, I have
import keller_protocol.keller_protocol as kp
....
..and so on..

After running test.py, there is this following error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/myfolder/test.py", line 1, in 
import keller_protocol.keller_protocol as kp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keller_protocol'

This module is installed by
pip install keller-protocol

I am wondering if anyone could help. Thanks.

I thought that perhaps this library has been not called properly so I specify where this library is in test.py but the answer is still the same.

Comment: How are you running test.py? In cmd or an ide? Make sure that it’s using python 3.10 from PATH.

Comment: I ran on terminal, Ubuntu 22.04 and tried running with python3.10, but the error message still appeared .

Comment: Can you run pip list and see if the keller_protocal library is there?

Comment: Yes. It's there, one of the installed packages.

Comment: confirm that you are running the same version of python as to where it is installed.

Comment: yes. I also checked with sys.path which leads to the same library folder.